# How to get the number of repetitions of a word in articles using aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I use 'term aggregation' to know how many times a word is repeated in elasticsearch. This method works properly for short string filed's.

my simple term aggregation :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "analyze_wildcard": true,
            "query": "*"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": []
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "msgtxt.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but in long string filed with long text like 'articles' it returns some long sentences.

Is it possible to find the number of repetitions using 'term aggregation' or other methods? ( article text is in Arabic/Persian language )

Answer (score 1):

I think you need term vector not aggregation for this case.
Here is the documentation
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-multi-termvectors.html

Comment: term vector return result for single document . multi term vector can do term vector function for about 1000 or more document in one time ?

Comment: I haven't test with more than 100 documents. But I think you can ;)

Comment: multi term vector return terms and freq for each document , and not for all document

Comment: Ok my bad, wrong solution.
I haven't try but significant terms could help maybe : 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-significantterms-aggregation.html